# Кнопка не меняет свой цвет

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите плиз, почему кнопки не мигают как задумано  (т.е. мигнула - задержка, снова мигнула другим цветом, и далее по циклу

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
 {
   button.BackColor = Color.Black;
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
   button.BackColor = Color.White;
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
 }
```

Comment: А где вы вызываете этот цикл?

Comment: Thread.Sleep(1000); "морозит" поток UI, а значит и попытку перекрасить кнопку. Используйте таймер.

Comment: Как вариант, можно использовать асинхронный код: `await Task.Delay(1000);`. При этом необходимо добавить `async` в сигнатуру метода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой способ, это дать команду приложению, чтобы оно обработало все события прежде чем `Sleep` его заморозит.

В самом начале кода добавьте

```scharp
using System.Threading;
```

Рядом с такими же юзингами, чтобы не повторять `System.Threading` в коде.

Затем

```csharp
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
   button.BackColor = Color.Black;
   Application.DoEvents();
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
   button.BackColor = Color.White;
   Application.DoEvents();
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

В противном случае обработка событий произойдет только тогда, когда цикл завершится. То есть пока вы моргаете кнопкой, окно не знает об этом, потому что приложение занято морганием кнопкой и перейдет к отрисовке окна только когда ваш код завершится, но будет уже поздно.

Есть и другие способы решения этой задачи - асинхронность (`async`/`await`) и многопоточность (`Task`). Но тема сложная и обширная.

Вот пример с асинхронностью.

```csharp
private async Task ButtonFlashAsync()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        button2.BackColor = Color.Black;
        await Task.Delay(75);
        button2.BackColor = Color.White;
        await Task.Delay(75);
    }
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2.Text = "Begin";
    await ButtonFlashAsync();
    button2.Text = "Finish";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, до асинхронности я пока не добрался, на моем текущем уровне это именно то что надо

Comment: @ЕвгенийМарков разница этого подхода с асинхронностью в том, что пока действует Sleep, вы не сможете ничего делать с окном, то есть не перетаскивать его, не жать другие кнопки, вообще ничего, приложение будет "висеть". При асинхронности этого не произойдет. Пример будет простой и я рекомендую вам ознакомиться с ним. Для этого добавьте в вопрос полностью свой `Button1_Click` или что у вас там (отредактируйте вопрос), где этот цикл расположен. Потом добавьте сюда комментарий, чтобы я увидел, что вам это интересно, и я сразу же перепишу ваш код под асинхронность, это дело нескольких секунд. :)

Comment: Лучше не использовать DoEvents. Это может принести большие проблемы. См. ответы здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5181777/5045688

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov лучше не использовать winforms :) но человек учится, экспериментирует, и ему надо объяснить, что и как работает.

Comment: _лучше не использовать winforms_ - с чего бы это? По опросу, проведённому мной среди меня (да, не совсем релевантная выборка), это лучший GUI-фреймворк для _большинства_ (не всех) случаев.

Comment: _но человек учится_ - ну так учите его сразу правильному. _и ему надо объяснить, что и как работает_ - но вы же не объяснили, как работает DoEvents внутри. ;)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я бы с радостью выдал пример для `async`/`await`, но автор отказался предоставить полный код метода, без которого, получились бы `await` в вакууме.

Comment: В моей задаче асинхронность как раз не нужна. Образно говоря, мне нужно чтобы нужные кнопки "проморгались", показывая себя, и после этого (но не параллельно) действие программы продолжалось

Comment: @ЕвгенийМарков асинхронность - не равно параллельность. Я вам выше уже рассказал про недостатки такого подхода. Есть и другие проблемы, которые могут быть вызваны использованием `DoEvents()`. Просто отредактируйте вопрос, положите туда весь метод целиком, и я вам покажу пример. А дальше уж сами решайте.

Comment: @ЕвгенийМарков добавил в ответ пример с асинхронностью.

Answer (score 0):

Ок, раз DoEvents - это плохо, по совету **aepot** попробовал сделать это через async / await
Вроде работает

```
public void Buttonflash()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                button2.BackColor = Color.Black;
                Thread.Sleep(75);
                button2.BackColor = Color.White;
                Thread.Sleep(75);
            }
        }
        public async void TestAsync()
        {
            button2.Text = "Begin";
            await Task.Run(()=> Buttonflash());
            button2.Text = "Finish";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TestAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Код добавьте в основной вопрос, а этот ответ удалите. Я добавил для вас правильно реализованный пример с асинхронностью.

Comment: Да, я не заметил. Спасибо, работает, но есть нюанс. Надпись на кнопке  становится "Finish" только после завершения цикла мигания цветом. Так и задумано? Я думал что асинхронность это как бы распараллеливание, то есть мигание идет отдельно от выполнения программы

Comment: `await` по сути запускает параллельную задачу и ждет ее завершения не блокируя текущий поток, то есть не замораживая интерфейс, это и есть запуск асинхронного кода. Код работает, не занимая текущий поток. Если вам очень интересно, как это работает, ищите материалы про async/await и Машину Состояний. Но как я выше писал, это сложная и обширная тема. Если кратко, то из достаточно простого кода компилятор делает большую асинхронную и отказоучтойчивую функцию, разбивая выполняемый код на части.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep()` замораживает текущий поток, а `await Task.Delay()` - нет. Но второй должен быть расположен внутри асинхронного метода.

Comment: Например, вы можете взять код из `ButtonFlashAsync()` и просто перенести в метод `button1_Click()`, и все будет работать точно так же.