# Асинхронный цикл for

Tags: c#, .net, асинхронность

Сегодня начал изучать C# и не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы программа не останавливалась несмотря на выполнение цикла

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ilovetests111
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) { 
            progressBar1.Value = i;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Task.Run(() => {Thread.Sleep(50)});

Comment: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);` -> `await Task.Delay(50);`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц плохой совет, как минимум потому что без await это не будет работать.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1112357/373567

Comment: ничего себе Вы темы выбираете для начала изучения,  Вы хотите чтобы прогресс бар не тормозил всю форму, в этом суть вопроса?

Comment: @DaniilLoban в том, что цикл синхронный и пока он не отработает, ui не обновится

Comment: я скажу больше  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50); останавливает поток исполнения

Answer (score -1):

В данном случае `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)` замораживает основной поток программы поэтому нужно создать дополнительный поток, который мы сможем замораживать не зависимо от основного.

Так как мы работаем с прогресс баром то для этой задачи отлично подходит класс `Progress` который инициализируется лямбдой для обновления интерфейса а вызывается она методом `Report`

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace progress
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(v => progressBar1.Value = v);
            Task.Run(() => { progressGo(progress); });
        }
        async void progressGo(IProgress<int> progress)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    progress.Report(i);
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `await Task.Delay(50)`, не? Зачем этот изврат, выже не под .NET 3.5 код пишете, верно?

Comment: Раз уж на то пошло, то познакомьтесь с интерфейсом `IProgress<T>` и классом `Progress<T>`. Пригодится в подобных фокусах.

Comment: cогласен, лучше ознакомиться