# Как изменять label через определённый промежуток времени c#?

Tags: c#

[image: Рабочее окно программы]

Здравствуйте! У меня есть программный код на языке C# (см. скриншот). Мне необходимо после нажатия на кнопку "Включить компьютер" показать пользователю, как увеличивается температура, к примеру, от 0 до 30, чтобы пользователь прям видел 1, 2, 3, 4 и так далее.

Прежде чем писать, я пробовал различные способы: через цикл, с использованием Thread.Sleep(). Однако программа зависает или выдаёт последнее значение.

У меня label с температурой это label7.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // что здесь нужно реализовать, чтобы пользователь видел изменение температуры на каждый градус
        label7.Text = "Температура: " + temperature;
       
    }
```

Температуру храню в переменной: temperature; первоначально переменная равна нулю.

Comment: Нельзя подвешивать `GUI`, обработчик события должен максимально быстро вернуть управление. Если по-старинке, то можете по клику включить `backgroungWorker` и в нём спать в `Thread.Sleep` и менять `lable`, только `BeginInvoke` не забыть когда элементы `GUI` трогаете. Но лучше сделать асинхронный обработчик клавиши, тогда можете там и цикл в принципе сделать с `await Task.Delay` внутри, если я ничего не путаю. Но ещё лучше - таск отдельный запустить из асинхронного обработчика и всё делать там, так будет совсем правильно.

Comment: По асинхронищине смотрите ссылку вверху в синем блоке. Про алгоритм поведения, попробуйте Конечный автомат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1382349/373567

Comment: @aepot здравствуйте, вы мне помогли! Спасибо. Хотел задать дополнительный вопрос: при нажатии на кнопку у меня начинает выполняться асинхронная функция. При клике, допустим, "выключить компьютер" мне нужно остановить эту функцию. Как это можно сделать, чтобы она перестала выполняться при клике на другую кнопку?

Comment: Я же вам дал решение, там 2 метода `StartLoop` и `StopLoop` - надо ли объяснять, что они делают?

Comment: @aepot я использовал эту ссылку: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1112087/
я видать не до конца понял, как прервать выполнение асинхронной функции при нажатие на кнопку?

Comment: Вторую смотрите, вы задаете вопрос, на который уже дан ответ.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо ещё раз, ссылка только сейчас мне отобразилась, где ответ дан. До этого её не было. Благодарю вас.